# how can a server handle lots of port 80 connections

Tags: web-server, port, connections

Admittedly this is a simple question but 20 minutes of googling and I just can't find an answer... I will frame my question with an example.

say I own www.reallypopular.com and my website sees 100 GET requests per second. Also let's say the average time for my server to respond to that GET request is 1 second (for the sake of the example just assume some server side processing.) My understanding of ports would say that the first client to contact my server would then block anyone else from connection to port 80 for 1 second. Following this logic, effectively only 1% of all users would actually be responded to and the rest would get "Port busy" or "not responding" or some such error.

Obviously I am missing something because this is clearly not what is happening so instead of proposing my theories as to why I'd love it if someone could set me straight here or point me to something I could read to clear this up. Thanks much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be found in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_number#Technical_details) wikipedia article:

> Applications implementing common
>   services often use specifically
>   reserved, well-known port numbers for
>   receiving service requests from client
>   hosts. This process is known as
>   listening and involves the receipt of
>   a request on the well-known port and
>   reestablishing **one-to-one
>   server-client communications on
>   another private port**, so that other
>   clients may also contact the
>   well-known service port.

Also, from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#accept.28.29) article on Berkeley sockets on wikipedia.

> When an application is listening for
>   stream-oriented connections from other
>   hosts, it is notified of such events
>   (cf. select() function) and must
>   initialize the connection using the
>   accept() function. Accept() creates a
>   **new socket for each connection** and
>   removes the connection from the listen
>   queue.

Comment: 60 seconds ahead of me AND you follow up with further information! Nice work. +1.

Answer (score 2):

When the client connects, and the TCP server accepts the connection, a **new socket** is created at the server for communication with this  client. The original listening socket continues to listen for new requests, and the new socket is used to send and receive from a  particular client. Note that a TCP server with N active clients will  have N sockets to read/write for each client, in addition to the  main listening socket. All these N+1 sockets are all supposed to be  on the **same port number** (the server's well known port number), but  they have different socket file descriptors inside the server code.

[Source](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~cs641/notes/lec04.txt)

Answer (score 1):

TCP doesn't work that way. A connection to a port from another system does not mean that port can't receive other connections. From the [wikipedia article on TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol):

> Arriving TCP data packets are
>   identified as belonging to a specific
>   TCP connection by its sockets, that
>   is, the combination of source host
>   address, source port, destination host
>   address, and destination port.